# Amcharts not zooming correctly

Tags: angular, amcharts4

I'am using amcharts 4 to draw a (about 12 Linecharts with 5000 points each) chart in an Angular application. It shows a quite big scale(-1.000.000 
 to 8.000.000). Zooming works well on lines with about 200 to -300, but as soon as I'am trying to zoom to -10 to 30 it won't zoom any further. The Line just sticks on the top of the chart, and the vertical zoom does nothing.

I tried to set the ValueAxis to valueAxis.minZoomFactor = 0; but it shows no reaction. Honestly I don't know where to start because there are so much options to try and it makes no sense to me that zooming works until the numbers get to small...

```js
this.valueAxis = this.chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
this.valueAxis.minZoomFactor = 0;
```

```js
const seriesOneHigh = this.chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
seriesOneHigh.dataFields.valueY = valueName;
seriesOneHigh.dataFields.dateX = 'date';
seriesOneHigh.strokeWidth = 2;
seriesOneHigh.name = name;
seriesOneHigh.yAxis = this.valueAxis;
seriesOneHigh.minBulletDistance = 10;
seriesOneHigh.tooltip.pointerOrientation = 'vertical';
seriesOneHigh.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 20;
seriesOneHigh.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 1;
seriesOneHigh.tooltip.label.padding(2, 10, 2, 10);
seriesOneHigh.tooltipText = '{name}: {valueY.formatNumber(\'#.00000000\')}';
```

```js
this.chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
this.chart.scrollbarY.parent = this.chart.leftAxesContainer;
this.chart.scrollbarY.toBack();
```

Thank you!

[Strange Chart zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1rAm.jpg)